# In angular2 service when value of service property changes - how corresponding component property reflects this change? Explain change detection

Tags: angular2-services, angular2-components, angular2-changedetection

In angular2 service, when value of **primitive properties of service** change- corresponding component properties don't change where as if **service has a user defined custom class as a property and if that changes - component reflects the change.** 
**Why, How change detection is working here?** 
In my application - I have a service with an array of custom object(Book). When user adds a new object to this array using AddComponent - this addition is reflected in ViewComponent even without reassigning the component's property to service's property, whereas when I use primitive types for service -> the changes don't reflect in the component. I need to know how change detection is working in both the cases, and why is it different.
Note: I have used routerreusestrategy so that routed component whose constructor has been loaded once doesn't reload its constructor - able to validate that once constructor has been called - it's not called again when routing back to the same component.
Code for my service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Book } from "../dto/book";

@Injectable()
export class BooksService{
private _books:Book[];
private addedNumber:Number;

getAddCount():Number{
    return this.addedNumber;
}

constructor(){
    this.addedNumber=0;
    this._books=[];
    let book=new Book(1,"akriti");
    this._books.push(book);
}

addBook(book:Book){
let matchFound=false;
    this._books.every(function(element){
        if(element.id==book.id){
            matchFound=true;
            return false;
        }
        else    
            return true;
    });
if(!matchFound){
    this._books.push(book);
}
this.addedNumber=20;
console.log("number: "+this.addedNumber);
}

fetchBook():Book[]{
    console.log("automatch");
    return this._books;
}
}
```

Code for my component to display book details:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Book } from "../dto/book";
import { BooksService } from "../service/books.service";

@Component({
templateUrl:'./view.books.component.html'
})
export class ViewBooksComponent{
private bookss:any;
private book:any;
private count:Number;
constructor(private booksService:BooksService){
    console.log("view books constructor");
    this.bookss=this.booksService.fetchBook();
    this.count=this.booksService.getAddCount();
}
}
```

Code for component's html: in which count is not reflecting as 20 but Book[] array reflecting change

```
View Books :
<div *ngFor="let boo of book">{{boo.id}}||{{boo.name}}</div>
Count is : {{count}}
```

Code for component which adds Book details to service: on its addBook function click, count is displayed as 20.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { BooksService } from "../service/books.service";
import { Book } from "../dto/book";

@Component({
templateUrl:'./add.books.component.html'
})
export class AddBooksComponent{
private books:Book[];
private id:number;
private name:string;
private count:Number;
constructor(private booksService:BooksService){
    console.log("constructor addbook");
    this.id=0;
    this.name="";
    this.books=this.booksService.fetchBook();
}
addBook(){
    console.log("inside addbook function for ts");
    let book=new Book(this.id,this.name);
    this.booksService.addBook(book);
    this.count=this.booksService.getAddCount();
}
}
```

Comment: Add books here :-
<div>
    Enter id : <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="id"/>
    Enter name : <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
    <button (click)="addBook()">Add Book</button>
</div>

View below books count {{count}} :-
<div *ngFor="let book of books">
   id:  {{book.id}} || name:  {{book.name}}
</div>

Comment: Above is the code for addition for book